# Not able to replace div text with innerHTML

Tags: cgi, innerhtml

I am trying to put different data from cgi output in different DIV
Did that with below code, but now when new data comes, it appends the DIV,
I want to replace the DIV data and not append it.

I am new to this, As I am a hardware engg. do not know much of coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Console</h1>
  <pre>
    <div id="d1" style="width: 25%; height: 200px; ">
</div>
<div id="d2" style="width: 25%; height: 200px; ">
   </div>
  </pre>
  <script>
    var source = new EventSource('/cgi-bin/data.cgi');
    source.onmessage = function(e) {
    var o = document.getElementById("d1");
    o.innerHTML += e.data1 + '<br>';
    var x = document.getElementById("d2");
    x.innerHTML += e.data2 + '<br>';

 };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just want to replace existing data in D1 with new data which is coming from CGI.

Comment: You are using ```o.innerHTL += ...```. If you just want to replace the data each time you can use ```o.innerHTML =...```.

Comment: Thanks ! please help me on  d2 data also, it is showing as undefined.

Comment: You need to understand what is found inside the ```e``` object passed to your method. And I would use the same code to update the inner html (x.innerHTML=)

Comment: My cgi output is id:autogen number data:xxxx , and id: autogen number, d2:xxxx . Now I am able to display data from data:xxxx , e.data works, e.d2 won't work. So I need to send data in different manner or read in different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do the following.

```
 o.innerHTML = e.data1 + '<br>';
```

just remove that "+" before "="

Comment: Yes please share it here

Comment: only d1 is updated , d2 updates as undefined. if I run cgi (python) on CLI, I get both d1 and d2.

Comment: you have to do the same for d2. just remove that +. and it should work fine. why you are getting d2 as undefined that's because on e there is no d2. please try to console the "e" and see what properties you got in "e".

Comment: I am not sending data, I am replacing data with d2 in python, so issue is I am not passing data:xxxx   , I am passing d2:xxxx  (xxxx=actual data),  for d1 I am passing data:xxxx so it is working.  any inputs for this ?